# Is there a way to return the currently logged on ID from Netezza in a view's SQL, current_sid

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a SQL statement on Netezza that uses the following SQL to acquire the currently logged on `user ID`:

```
SELECT SESSION_USERNAME FROM _V_SESSION_DETAIL WHERE SESSION_ID=current_sid
```

This works great when I'm executing the SQL in a database client. However, when I implement the above SQL in a view (along with other SQL) the `current_sid` is replaced with the `session ID` I happened to have when I created the view. That SQL will then look something like:

```
SELECT DEFINITION_SCHEMA."_V_SESSION_DETAIL".SESSION_USERNAME FROM DEFINITION_SCHEMA."_V_SESSION_DETAIL" WHERE (DEFINITION_SCHEMA."_V_SESSION_DETAIL".SESSION_ID = 2434740
```

Is there a way to define a view that will get the currently logged on `user's ID`, not the ID that was assigned when the view was created?

Comment: Could you please share the view definition that you want to create

Comment: I have reduced the view a bit, but here it is:

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ADMIN.VW_PI_HRCHY_EPH AS 
WITH SECURITY_GRP_CNT (COUNT) AS 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) 
   FROM _V_USERGROUPS
   WHERE USERNAME IN (SELECT SESSION_USERNAME FROM _V_SESSION_DETAIL WHERE SESSION_ID=current_sid)
         AND GROUPNAME='GROUP_AUTH2READ'),
CHAR_MASK (CHAR_MASK_CHAR) AS (SELECT 'xxx' FROM _V_SESSION_DETAIL LIMIT 1),
NUM_MASK (NUM_MASK_NUM) AS (SELECT -1 FROM _V_SESSION_DETAIL LIMIT 1),

Comment: TS_MASK (TS_MASK_TS) AS (SELECT '1000-01-01 00:00:00' FROM _V_SESSION_DETAIL LIMIT 1)
SELECT CASE WHEN SECURITY_GRP_CNT.COUNT > 0 THEN PI_HRCHY.HRCHY_LINE_ID    ELSE NUM_MASK.NUM_MASK_NUM END AS HRCHY_LINE_ID,
 CASE WHEN SECURITY_GRP_CNT.COUNT > 0 THEN PI_HRCHY.LOCALE_CD        ELSE CHAR_MASK.CHAR_MASK_CHAR END AS LOCALE_CD, 
 CASE WHEN SECURITY_GRP_CNT.COUNT > 0 THEN PI_HRCHY.MODIFY_TS        ELSE TS_MASK.TS_MASK_TS END AS MODIFY_TS

Comment: FROM SECURITY_GRP_CNT, ADMIN.PI_HRCHY, CHAR_MASK, NUM_MASK, TS_MASK
WHERE ((PI_HRCHY.HRCHY_TYP_ID = 11) AND (PI_HRCHY.ACTV_IND = 'Y'::"NCHAR"));

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Netezza Metadata functions(ex. `current_sid`) are not supported in `with` clause and would advice to remove them from with and to include them in the base query .

```
CREATE
    OR REPLACE VIEW ADMIN.VW_PI_HRCHY_EPH AS
    WITH CHAR_MASK(CHAR_MASK_CHAR) AS (
            SELECT 'xxx'
            FROM _V_SESSION_DETAIL LIMIT 1
            )
        ,NUM_MASK(NUM_MASK_NUM) AS (
            SELECT - 1
            FROM _V_SESSION_DETAIL LIMIT 1
            )
        ,TS_MASK(TS_MASK_TS) AS (
            SELECT '1000-01-01 00:00:00'
            FROM _V_SESSION_DETAIL LIMIT 1
            )

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN SECURITY_GRP_CNT.COUNT > 0
            THEN PI_HRCHY.HRCHY_LINE_ID
        ELSE NUM_MASK.NUM_MASK_NUM
        END AS HRCHY_LINE_ID
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SECURITY_GRP_CNT.COUNT > 0
            THEN PI_HRCHY.LOCALE_CD
        ELSE CHAR_MASK.CHAR_MASK_CHAR
        END AS LOCALE_CD
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SECURITY_GRP_CNT.COUNT > 0
            THEN PI_HRCHY.MODIFY_TS
        ELSE TS_MASK.TS_MASK_TS
        END AS MODIFY_TS
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM _V_USERGROUPS
    WHERE USERNAME IN (
            SELECT SESSION_USERNAME
            FROM _V_SESSION_DETAIL
            WHERE SESSION_ID = current_sid
            )
        AND GROUPNAME = 'GROUP_AUTH2READ'
    ) SECURITY_GRP_CNT
    ,ADMIN.PI_HRCHY
    ,CHAR_MASK
    ,NUM_MASK
    ,TS_MASK
WHERE (
        (PI_HRCHY.HRCHY_TYP_ID = 11)
        AND (PI_HRCHY.ACTV_IND = 'Y'::"NCHAR")
        );
```

Comment: @BrianB  If this solution is useful request you to please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

The solution NzGuy provided solved my problem.  As he stated, apparently placing the current_sid contact in the WITH clause of the SQL causes the constant to be evaluated differently than if it were placed outside the WITH. The common table expression defined outside the WITH clause resolved my problem.